# 7zip: How to exclude files (not file types) using an exclude list file?

Tags: command-line, 7-zip, exclude

I know you can create a text file containing a list of files and then tell 7zip to reference this file so that it can exclude them from the archive, but I cannot find the syntax for that.  Can someone help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After a few hours of searching, I finally figured it out.  Here's the switch syntax:

`7z a -xr@exclude.txt backup.7z c:\whatever\*`

Notice `-xr` instead of `-x`.  The `r` indicates recursive so it can match excluded files in deep folder hierarchies.  Also, the format of the text file can be at least ANSI or UTF-8.

As for the file containing the files, as OldWolf said, it's a list separated by carriage returns like this:

```
Telerik.Reporting.dll
Telerik.Reporting.Service.dll
Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll
Telerik.Web.Design.dll
Telerik.Web.UI.dll
*.txt
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to do exclude with the wildcard option and it turns out I was missing the `r` option. This is the correct way to exclude PNG files recursively in bash (single quotes to stop bash from expanding `!` and `*`):  `-xr'!*.png'`  (edit: single quotes instead of escape)

Answer (score 4):

I think you want the -x switch with @

```
7z a -t7z my.zip * -x@myexclusion.lst
```

In retrospect, I realized you may have meant you wanted the syntax for the listfile. It should be a newline separated list. You may be running into an encoding issue. 7z expects it to be in UTF-8 format, you can override that with the -scs switch or you can tell notepad to save the file in UTF-8 format

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about file encoding. I have been puzzling for hours as to why my exclusion list was not being obeyed. I produce the file in a PowerShell script using Out-File which defaults to Unicode. Changing it to output UTF8 and suddenly everything just works.

Answer (score 0):

If your list is going to be really short, you can have more than one -x flag:

7z a -r CppSourceJBR.zip *.cpp *.h -x!stdafx.* -x!targetver.h

BTW while testing I had to keep deleting the .zip file. When I forgot that, for instance targetver.h was still in the ZIP from the last run.